# Input validation fails when importing an Akamai Property into Pulumi

Tags: akamai, pulumi

Following the [directions](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/akamai/property/#import) for importing an Akamai Property into pulumi, but running a command like `pulumi import akamai:index/property:Property example_property prp_00000,ctr_M-00000,grp_000000` gives me the validation error below.

```
Diagnostics:
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (akamai-import-dev):
    error: preview failed

  akamai:index:Property (example_property):
    error: akamai:index/property:Property resource 'example_property' has a problem: ExactlyOne: "group_id": one of `group,group_id` must be specified
    error: akamai:index/property:Property resource 'example_property' has a problem: ExactlyOne: "contract_id": one of `contract,contract_id` must be specified
    error: Preview failed: one or more inputs failed to validate
```

It's strange because I've specified the property_id, contract_id, and group_id in the command.

Answer (score 0):

I've opened https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-akamai/issues/30 to address the error itself.

As a workaround, using the import resource option as described at https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/adopting/import/#pulumi-import-resource-operation should allow the resource to be imported and avoid this error.

For example:

```js
const example = new akamai.Property("example", {
    //  add your resource properties here
}, { 
    // run `pulumi up` with this set will import the resource, then you can remove this line on subsequent updates
    import: "prp_00000,ctr_M-00000,grp_000000" 
} );
```